# Closing Visual Studio 2015 results in 'Microsoft.AppInsights.HockeyApp.IHockeyAppProvider' error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try to click the red X on Visual Studio 2015, alt+F4, or right-click and close from the task bar I get the following message:

[image: Error when closing Visual Studio]

The only thing that allows me to close Visual Studio is to open task manager and kill the devenv.exe

How do I get rid of this error?